# Where are some current Ruby & RoR resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been a PHP Developer for a few years now and I've recently been interested in learning Ruby & Rails but I've found a lot of the resources I've found seem to be dated and not for Rails 2.0 or Ruby 1.8.6 etc... can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm running OSX 10.6 with the default ruby & rails installation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Great place to get started, check out the "Getting Started with Rails" guide first.

If you want to purchase a book to help you out, [Agile Web Development With Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166) from the Pragmatic Bookshelf is an excellent and useful read.

Answer (score 7):

Great book for starting out:

http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition

---

Very thorough and up-to-date tutorial:

http://www.railstutorial.org/

---

Great free screencasts once you know your way around Rails a bit:

http://railscasts.com/ (or the text version at http://asciicasts.com/)

Hint: concentrate on the most recent ones, as the further back you go the older the info is and the more likely it is to be outdated.

---

These sceencasts aren't free, but they're very nice as well:

http://peepcode.com/

http://envycasts.com/

*(update: community wiki)*

Comment: ++ to Agile Web Development.  Its my Rails bible

Comment: Railscasts +1. Ryan Bates is a very reputable member of the Rails community. Good luck, @aaroninfidel :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) when you have questions :-)  By design, it should be up-to-date.